# Class Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\Rolemiddleware does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel , when I am trying to inject middleware in router getting some error

my router code

```
<?php

Route::get('role',[
    'middleware' => 'Role:editor',
    'uses' => 'TestController@index',
])->middleware('role');

?>
```

kernal.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'Age' => \App\Http\Middlware\AgeMiddleware::class,
        'Role' => \App\Http\Middlware\RoleMiddleware::class,
    ];
```

RoleMiddleware.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class RoleMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
    {
        echo "Role: ".$role;
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

?>

Here is my TestController code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;


class Firstcontroller extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        echo '<br>First Controller';
    }

?>
```

I am getting an error: Class Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\Rolemiddleware does not exist. I am new to Laravel and using Laravel 5.3. Can you please tell me why it is giving me an error

Comment: 'Role' => \App\Http\Middlware\RoleMiddleware::class, there is a spelling istake in the word Middleware

Comment: Hi user2226181,

Thanks for replying but I am sorry I did this spelling mistake in Stck flow while writing this issue, My code have correct spelling Middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In kernal.php you are doing spelling mistake in word  `Middlware`

change this

```
'Age' => \App\Http\Middlware\AgeMiddleware::class,
  'Role' => \App\Http\Middlware\RoleMiddleware::class,
```

to

```
'Age' => \App\Http\Middleware\AgeMiddleware::class,
'Role' => \App\Http\Middleware\RoleMiddleware::class,
```

Comment: Hi iCoders,

Thanks for replying but I am sorry I did this spelling mistake in Stck flow while writing this issue, My code have correct spelling Middleware

Comment: Thanks man, I get the issue, actually the issue was in the path of Middleware in Kernal.php 

'Age' => \App\Http\Middleware\AgeMiddleware::class,

I was using wrong path

Comment: @user2226181.okay.Thanks